# How to decompose a Canvas to 6*6 cells

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

Now, I create a Canvas as my 2D RPG's Map . Indeed, I create a array cells[6*6].

```
        int x=6;
        int y=6 ;
        bool[,] cells = new bool[x,y];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            {
                cells[i, j] = true;
            }
        }
```

And then

```
<Window x:Class="ASTHENIA.GameIng"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="ASTHENIA" Height="650" Width="800" ResizeMode="NoResize" Closed="Window_Closed_1" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Grid Name="MyGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="0.05*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.02*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.02*" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3"  Width="100" Height="80" Click="Button_Click_1"  >
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/back.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" />

    <Canvas Name="Map" Grid.Row ="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" >

    </Canvas>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

How to decompose the Canvas to 6*6. And the first left of cells is cell[0,0].

Comment: What do you mean by "decompose the canvas?"  What have you tried, and why isn't it working?

Comment: or resolve the canvas..for example ..Here i create a [6,6] array. Then i want to resolve the canvas.6*6 cells.

Comment: What do you mean by "resolve?"  Do you mean you want to draw a grid on the canvas?

Comment: Yeah, same as the grid. “RowDefinitions"...

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a canvas?

A canvas is a raw **uniform surface**, and you want a **matrix-like surface**.

So you'd rather use a [**UniformGrid**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.uniformgrid.aspx) with elements being small canvas.

Or you can write you're own matrix-like surface control...

Comment: So you'll have to draw each cell on the canvas manually; e.g. by creating and adding Rectangles (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle.aspx)

Comment: Actually, How to draw the each cell?

Comment: Each cell will be represented by a rectangle so: "Map.Children.Add(rectangle);"

Comment: Right, but how to make the first left of top cells is cell[0,0]